# Filter the no-responses questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, unanswered-questions

Is there a way to get the list of (recent) questions for which the poor souls authors didn't get any answer (0 response) yet?
There is such a fast rotation in questions that a few may have joined Voyager2 on the outer edges of space every day.

- a way that I didn't see (after honestly searching for 2 mn)
- or maybe a script / (scriptmonkey?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do a search for **answers:0**, then hit the newest tab.

The direct URL for that is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0).

Comment: Wow! I guess the **k** means something.